# Laravel Multi table auth

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

I have three tables
**Admins** for admin,
**Teachers** for teacher,
**students** for student.

Each of these users have their own dashboard (AdminDash, TeacherDash, StudentDash). Now all I want to do is, each user are sent to their respective dashboard after login. Is it even possible to do so.

Also can this be done using single login form or do I need to create different login form for each case and different controllers to authenticate.

Edit:
Actually, here teachers and students fill different registration forms with different value so I don't want to store them in same table. And admins is for admin and superadmin who run the site. Also the dashboard they use after login are different.

Comment: Why are you making them their own tables when they can just be `roles` of a single `user` tables?

Comment: I have added some information in edit section. Would you like to check please @fyroc

Comment: still should be the same table that’s polymorphic and relates to other tables depending on the role

Answer (score 0):

I published a custom laravel for manage multi auth in one laravel project. In example branch I commit step by step for describe everything you most know. [larasin](https://gitlab.com/larasin/larasin)

> Also can this be done using single login form or do I need to create different login form for each case and different controllers to authenticate.

You can create a login form component an use it every where you want.

Answer (score 0):

First extend your 3 tables with Authenticable like:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
```

Then in your config/auth, set up the providers like:

```
'teachers' => [
    'driver' => 'eloquent',
    'model' => App\Models\Teacher::class,
 ],
```

Then you should be able to auth::attempt your model instance. 
Do let me know if this doesn't work, I am pretty new in Laravel also :) cheers!

*p/s: I do think it is better to just use a user table with a "role" column, however I believe you probably have different columns needed for each of these user groups. But you can still use new tables such as "teacher_profiles","user_profiles" for those columns, and you can refer to different tables according to your role. 
For example, if "teacher" role_id is 3, then if user role==3, you will refer to "teacher_profiles" table.*